# elementor - execute javascript after custom form submit action

Tags: elementor

I added a custom "after form submit" action for elementor but if I recho some result I get console errors when using "submit_success" event listener:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: originalEvent is not defined (common.min.js)
Uncaught TypeError: e.data is undefined (preloaded-elements-handlers.min)
```

I don't know what to return to avoid them and get my code executed. Maybe I use a wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself: I need to use the `$ajax_handler` method like `$ajax_handler->data['hello world']` inside the run() function.